# To mimic sort command of linux, to sort lines of a text file

Tags: c, sorting, pointers, file-handling

Sort command of linux must sort the lines of a text file and transfer the output to another file. But my code gives a runtime error. Please rectify the pointer mistakes so that output.

In which line exactly should I make changes? Because there is no output after all.

I'm pasting the whole code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void sortfile(char **arr, int linecount) {
    int i, j;
    char t[500];

    for (i = 1; i < linecount; i++) {
        for (j = 1; j < linecount; j++) {
            if (strcmp(arr[j - 1], arr[j]) > 0) {
                strcpy(t, arr[j - 1]);
                strcpy(arr[j - 1], arr[j]);
                strcpy(arr[j], t);
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    FILE *fileIN, *fileOUT;

    fileIN = fopen("test1.txt", "r");

    unsigned long int linecount = 0;
    int c;
    if (fileIN == NULL) {
        fclose(fileIN);
        return 0;
    }

    while ((c = fgetc(fileIN)) != EOF) {
        if (c == '\n')
            linecount++;
    }

    printf("line count=%d", linecount);
    char *arr[linecount];
    char singleline[500];

    int i = 0;
    while (fgets(singleline, 500, fileIN) != NULL) {
        arr[i] = (char*)malloc(500);
        strcpy(arr[i], singleline);
        i++;
    }

    sortfile(arr, linecount);

    for (i = 0; i < linecount; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", arr[i]);
    }
    fileOUT = fopen("out.txt", "w");
    if (!fileOUT) {
        exit(-1);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < linecount; i++) {
        fprintf(fileOUT, "%s", arr[i]);
    }

    fclose(fileIN);
    fclose(fileOUT);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code is you do not rewind the input stream after reading it the first time to count the number of newlines.  You should add `rewind(fileIN);` before the next loop.

Note however that there are other problems in this code:

- the number of newline characters may be less than the number of successful calls to `fgets()`: lines longer than 499 bytes will be silently broken in multiple chunks, causing more items to be read by `fgets()` than newlines.  Also the last line might not end with a newline. Just count the number of successful calls to `fgets()`.
- You allocate 500 bytes for each line, which is potentially very wasteful. Use `strdup()` to allocate only the necessary size.
- Swapping the lines in the sort routine should be done by swapping the pointers, not copying the contents.
- allocating `arr` with `malloc` is safer and more portable than defining it as a variable sized array with `char *arr[linecount];`

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void sortfile(char **arr, int linecount) {
    for (;;) {
        int swapped = 0;
        for (int j = 1; j < linecount; j++) {
            if (strcmp(arr[j - 1], arr[j]) > 0) {
                char *t = arr[j - 1];
                arr[j - 1] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = t;
                swapped = 1;
            }
        }
        if (swapped == 0)
            break;
    }
}

int main() {
    FILE *fileIN, *fileOUT;
    char singleline[500];
    int i, linecount;

    fileIN = fopen("test1.txt", "r");
    if (fileIN == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open %s\n", "test1.txt");
        return 1;
    }

    linecount = 0;
    while (fgets(singleline, 500, fileIN)) {
        linecount++;
    }

    printf("line count=%d\n", linecount);

    char **arr = malloc(sizeof(*arr) * linecount);
    if (arr == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "memory allocation failure\n");
        return 1;
    }

    rewind(fileIN);
    for (i = 0; i < linecount && fgets(singleline, 500, fileIN) != NULL; i++) {
        arr[i] = strdup(singleline);
        if (arr[i] == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "memory allocation failure\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    fclose(fileIN);

    if (i != linecount) {
        fprintf(stderr, "line count mismatch: i=%d, lilnecount=%d\n",
                i, linecount);
        linecount = i;
    }

    sortfile(arr, linecount);

    for (i = 0; i < linecount; i++) {
        printf("%s", arr[i]);
    }
    fileOUT = fopen("out.txt", "w");
    if (!fileOUT) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open %s\n", "out.txt");
        return 1;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < linecount; i++) {
        fprintf(fileOUT, "%s", arr[i]);
    }
    fclose(fileOUT);

    for (i = 0; i < linecount; i++) {
        free(arr[i]);
    }
    free(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

To get a different sort order, you would change the comparison function. Instead of `strcmp()` you could use this:

```c
#include <ctype.h>

int my_strcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2) {
    /* compare strings lexicographically but swap lower and uppercase letters */
    unsigned char c, d;
    while ((c = *s1++) == (d = *s2++)) {
        if (c == '\0')
            return 0;   /* string are equal */
    }
    /* transpose case of c */
    if (islower(c)) {
        c = toupper(c);
    } else {
        c = tolower(c);
    }
    /* transpose case of d */
    if (islower(d)) {
        d = toupper(d);
    } else {
        d = tolower(d);
    }
    /* on ASCII systems, we should still have c != d */
    /* return comparison result */
    if (c <= d)
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way I can modify the code to print the lines starting with small letters first and Capital letters later (i.e opposite to that of the order of ascii values).I'm learning how to code and it would reallly help.

Comment: @smruthibt: I amended the answer with a different comparison function for this order.